# MyBatis Nullpointer related to @Autowired

Tags: nullpointerexception, mybatis, autowired

I'm trying to write a program that will write to a mySql database using myBatis.  I need to create a table containing id's and values.  Currently I have a tag class, which holds these values, a tag dao interface, a tag xml implementation, and a main method.  I am getting a nullpointer exception that I think is related to the @Autowired statement.  If I use the @Autowired statement when I initialize the interface and the @Param statement when I write the interface, where in the code does my program know where to find the bean containing the information to find the xml file?

Comment: Are you using Spring? If yes, please post the relevant configuration.

Answer (score 0):

It depends how you are configuring Spring DI. I'd recommend configuring your application using Java configuration over XML, but it's personal preference. Take a look at the Spring documentation for Java configuration [here](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/3.0.x/spring-framework-reference/html/beans.html#beans-java).